# wordpress Contact form 7 validation not aligning to respective input

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, forms

I have the plugin "contact form 7" on my Wordpress site and I got stuck on how to align the validation messages properly.

this is the response when ever I try the output design.

[image]

This is the HTML form I added to my "contact form 7".

```
[response]
[text* your-name class:rounded-input class:cols-4 placeholder "Your Name"]
[text* your-position class:rounded-input class:cols-4 placeholder "Position"]
[text* company class:rounded-input class:cols-4 placeholder "Company Name"]
[email* your-email class:rounded-input class:cols-4 placeholder "Email Name"]

<label class="center-content">
    [checkbox* agreement class:rounded-input "I’m looking for the best solution with fantastic local support."]
</label>

    [submit class:button "Get a Solution"]

<p><small>*Your privacy is very important to us. To learn more about our information processesing procedures, please visit our <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>.</small></p>
```

Then here is the HTML in my PHP file:

```
<footer class="contact-form clearfix" style="background-image: url(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/contact-bg.png)">
    <div class="form-holder">
    <h2>Together, we’ll do great.</h2>
    <p> Cras venenatis feugiat nibh quis tempus. Quisque libero nibh, consequat posuere,<br> tempus pulvinar purus.</p>

    <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="66" title="Contact form"]'); ?>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Then this is my stylesheet for my footer form:

```
.form-holder {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 5%;
    color: #fff;
}

.rounded-input {
    max-width: 1020px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

.rounded-input.cols-4 {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 23%;
    margin: 15px 1%;
    background: transparent;
    color: #fff;
}
```

I am thinking of wrapping them inside a `div`.

Comment: Whats the css of the validation message? And the according html. I think its merely a position or display property.

Comment: Add the generated HTML (with the error messages) it would be easier to debug.

Comment: I've already done wrapping each input on a div and added some properties. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your html you have allocated 18 col's, you can only use 12 cols, so change the shortcode to

```
[text* your-name class:rounded-input class:cols-3 placeholder "Your Name"]
```